# How to get rid of Material Symbols flickering in Next.js 14?

Tags: next.js, material-ui, server-side-rendering

Using `readme.md` in [this repo](https://github.com/marella/material-symbols/tree/main/material-symbols#readme), I implemented Material Symbols to a Next.js project (version 14.0.4) via the second approach (import in `globals.css` file).

When the page is loading (SSR), the icon is invisible. When the page loads, the icon appears. I want the icon to be either server rendered, so it would be visible instantly, or not to flicker (width of the being loaded icon should be static).

Alternatively, I can create a skeleton for the whole button, but how would I check if it's being loaded?

Behavior presented under this link: https://imgur.com/a/tTJ8E5u